# SQLite not catching up with multiple requests in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

In my C# program I use SQLite for database storage.
The problem is that each time I try to do multiple write operations within a loop, I get a "disk I/O error" and then the DB file is corrupted.
I guess this has to do with DB not catching up with requests.
The problem is solved if I put a Thread.Sleep(...) in the loop, but this is not the optimal solution.
All DB requests are executed in the same thread, different than the UI's one.
So, is there a way to read the DB's ready-state before proceeding to the next request?

Comment: You could try setting the Journal mode to "Truncate" or even "OFF" to speed it up.  But Off will mean that you have no rollback possibility.  https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode

Comment: You can also try to enable enhanced errors, to try and find out what the real reason is:  http://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html

Comment: Can you post some code, so it's easier for someone else to reproduce?

Comment: @Alexandru-DanPop here's a snippet:

foreach (ListViewItem lvi in mylist.SelectedItems)
{
    DB.Execute("DELETE FROM main WHERE unique_id='" + lvi.Text + "';";
}

The I/O error occurs after 150-200 deletes.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Thanks for the tip. Changing journal_mode didn't help. Is there a way to group multiple DB operations into just one in order to be executed as whole?

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, setting Journal Mode to "WAL" seems to solve all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this directly after opening the connection:

```
pragma journal_mode = WAL
```

then

```
pragma busy_timeout = 30000
```

Try again?  This forces the db to use WALs with a 30sec time out.  This should allow plenty of time for you disk spin up to catch up with the C code.